# Empty tableview results from Backendless Query, how to populate into table

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

Working on a questions and answer app similar to Quora. Moving from Parse to Backendless.

The app compiles, I see data in the output, but the `tableview` is empty. the data isnt appending the array? (using Swift 2, Xcode 7.2)

```
    import UIKit


class QuestionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
    var showAllQuestions = [String]()
    //var showAllQuestions = [String:AnyObject] = [Question]() as [String:AnyObject]
    var currentQuestion = [Question]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Types.tryblock({ () -> Void in

            let startTime = NSDate()
            let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
            var allQuestions = self.backendless.persistenceService.of(Question.ofClass()).find(query)
            print("Total Questions in the Backendless starage - \(allQuestions.totalObjects)")

            let bc1 : BackendlessCollection = allQuestions as BackendlessCollection
            for order : Question in bc1.data as! [Question] {

                self.showAllQuestions.appendContentsOf(self.showAllQuestions)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
            var size = allQuestions.getCurrentPage().count
            while size > 0 {
                print("Loaded \(allQuestions) questions in the current page")
                allQuestions = allQuestions.nextPage()
                size = allQuestions.getCurrentPage().count
            }

            print("Total time (ms) - \(1000*NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime))")
            },

            catchblock: { (exception) -> Void in
                print("Server reported an error: \(exception as! Fault)")
            }
        )

    }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return showAllQuestions.count
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("questionCell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionsTableViewCell


        cell.userNameLabel.text = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row]
        cell.questionLabel?.text = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
```

This outputs this:

```
Total Questions in the Backendless starage - 8
```

`Loaded <BackendlessCollection> -> type: BloQuery2.Question, offset: 0, pageSize: 100, totalObjects: 8, data: (
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab60091f0>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab3e1f280>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600aae0>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600bbf0>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600cd80>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600ddf0>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600eeb0>",
    "<BloQuery2.Question: 0x7faab600ffa0>"
), query: <BackendlessDataQuery> -> properties: (null), whereClause: (null), queryOptions: <QueryOptions> -> {
    offset = 0;
    pageSize = 100;
    related =     (
    );
} questions in the current page
Total time (ms) - 1122.19899892807`

Comment: what does this line mean - `self.showAllQuestions.appendContentsOf(self.showAllQuestions)`? Amd, why you are updating the table in the loop?

Comment: @FahriAzimov Im trying to get the data out of the loop, so that it can be accessed by the cell in the table. The code clearly accesses the data on Backendless, just dont know proper way to pull it out and get it into the tableview. I had the query code within the cellForRowAtIndexPath, and that only returned the first question, and it also didnt allow for the numberOfRowsInSection to include the .count

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data is in the "self.allQuestions"? 
It is not coming as String. It is of type BloQuery2.Question
Please change the type through any function to get the Value as String from "BloQuery2.Question".

Comment: change your method to  cell.userNameLabel.text = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row] 
to              cell.userNameLabel.text  = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row] as! String

Comment: Not sure what you mean by self.Questions?  making the change you offered, adding the as! String had no change and it resulted this caution `Forced cast of 'String' to same type has no effect`

Comment: sorry it is self.allQuestions

Comment: Question is the class defined on Backendless. The code for the entity is here `import UIKit
import Foundation

class Question: NSObject {
        
    var question : String?
    var userName : String?
    var objectId: String?
    var created : NSDate?
    var owner:BackendlessUser?
    
    
    
    }`

Comment: Please change the code from

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

let onequestion = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row]
cell.userNameLabel.text = one question. userName as? String
cell.questionLabel?.text = onequestion.question as String

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code from

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

```
  let blocQuery:BloQuery2 = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row] as BloQuery2
    let onequestion:Question = blockQuery.Question as Question
    cell.userNameLabel.text = onequestion.userName as? String
    cell.questionLabel?.text = onequestion.question as String
```

Comment: I made that change and it resulted in  `Value of type 'String' has no member 'question'`

Comment: Have you changed its type to string?

Comment: I made that change, will not compile with same error as listed above. `Value of type String has no member "......"`

Comment: I have changed my question. Kindly try this

Comment: I get this error `Use of undeclared type 'BloQuery2'
`Cannot use module 'BloQuery2' as a type`

Comment: The code representing the change you offered, or the whole thing?

Comment: `let blocQuery:BloQuery2 = showAllQuestions[indexPath.row] as BloQuery2`
        `let onequestion:Question = blocQuery.Question as Question`
       `cell.userNameLabel.text = onequestion.userName! as String`
        `cell.questionLabel?.text = onequestion.question! as String`